# remove instances of a stack in swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

Whenever this function is call in my swift app the stack starts to build up, This function gets called several times, how can i remove all other instances of the view that have been generated and only show the latest view:

```
func dots() -> some View {
        if isSendingMessage {
            return AnyView(HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text(dotAnimationText) // Use the @State variable directly
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(1))
                        .opacity(isSendingMessage ? 1 : 0)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                        .font(.system(size: 36)) // Adjust the font size as needed
                        .lineLimit(1) // Ensure the text fits in a single line
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5) // Scale down the text if needed
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        .frame(width: 110, height: 40)
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        
                }
                .frame(width: 70) // Adjust the width of the fixed-size container
                Spacer()
            }
            .onAppear {
                startAnimation()
            })
        } else {
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
```

Comment: There looks like there's some missing context here, but in general, SwiftUI view hierarchy should be declarative -- you shouldn't have to "remove" other instances. I'm guessing you're storing the instances of `AnyView` somewhere and reusing them, which is a red flag. I'd suggest looking through some SwiftUI tutorials to get familiar with how the framework is used and definitely watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that we are missing some information here, generally try to define your views ***declaratively***, instead of trying to create functions which will return some views:

- Declare views you want to display as `var ...: some View`.
- Use a `@ViewBuilder` to load views based on condition

So something like this:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State var dotAnimationText: String = "Example"
    @State var isSendingMessage: Bool = true // Just an example
    
    @ViewBuilder var body: some View { // <-- Using @ViewBuilder to load a view conditionally
        if isSendingMessage { // <-- using a condition to display a corresponding view
            sendingMessageView
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
    
    private var sendingMessageView: some View { // <-- Declaring the view
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text(dotAnimationText) // Use the @State variable directly
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(1))
                    .opacity(isSendingMessage ? 1 : 0)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .font(.system(size: 36)) // Adjust the font size as needed
                    .lineLimit(1) // Ensure the text fits in a single line
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5) // Scale down the text if needed
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .frame(width: 110, height: 40)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    
            }
            .frame(width: 70) // Adjust the width of the fixed-size container
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            startAnimation()
        }
    }
    
    func startAnimation() {
        
    }
}
```